# How can my argument be used to create a matlab file?

Tags: python

I am writing a function that converts a 2d python array into a matlab file.  Here is my code so far...

```
def save_array(arr,fname):

import scipy.io 
import numpy



out_dict={}

out_dict[fname]=arr

scipy.io.savemat(fname.mat,out_dict)`
```

I want fname to be a string, but I am not sure how I can get the savemat part to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the reference docs for how to call savemat: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np

def save_array(arr, arrname, fname):
    """
    Save an array to a .mat file
    Inputs:
      arr: ndarray to save
      arrname: name to save the array as (string)
      fname: .mat filename (string)
    """
    out_dict={arrname: arr}
    scipy.io.savemat(fname,out_dict)

save_array(np.array([1,2,3]), 'arr', 'test.mat')
```

Might be worth doing a python tutorial or two. This is very basic stuff!

Comment: Alsom the fname should have included the .mat.  OK, that was my issue.  Thanks